# Having (old) jars on the classpath of a JDK 11 project [eclipse]

Tags: eclipse, jar, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I've finally tried to set up a modularised Java project with JDK 11, but I don't seem to be using the module and classpath properly. So far, I have done nothing but create the project and add the [Apache Commons IO 2.6](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to its classpath. **The module file is still empty.**

Then I created a test class and used one of the Apache classes and that's where it gets confusing to me. Eclipse's auto-completion offers me the Apache classes fine and even adds the import as it should, but then **the same import cannot be resolved.**

Check the screenshots below to see what I mean.

[image: The Module and the Class Path]

[image: Auto-Completion Works Fine]

[image: Import Cannot be Resolved]

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You must declare a `requires` directive in your `module-info.java` file for the dependency.

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (or move the JAR from the _Classpath_ to the _Modulepath_ and add the JAR as module in `module-info.java` via `requires ...`).

Comment: I'd really like to work with the `module-info.java` file, but the Apache Commons library apparently has not been designed as a java module (yet). So, whenever I add it to the module info, it says "`org.apache. ... cannot be resolved to a module.`"

Comment: Also, how exactly would I add it anyway? I have tried to address its packages as modules, but that, of course, couldn't work.

`module MM_Utils {
 requires org.apache.commons.io.output;
}`

Comment: It looks like the library uses `org.apache.commons.io` as the "automatic module name". That's the name the module system will use when the dependency is not a proper module but is used as a module (i.e. an "automatic module").  Given this, it should be `requires org.apache.commons.io;`. I can[t remember, but you may need to put the library on the modulepath rather than the classpath.

Comment: That did the trick - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Slaw's comment, the following tweak worked for me:

- Add the jar on the **module** path.
- Add the Apache Common's 'auto module' (i.e. the default module?) in the module-info file, in this case: `requires org.apache.commons.io;`